# SQL Join raw query issue on similar coloumn

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, join

Here is my report table

```
report
id user_id field_tech_id
1  1       4
2  3       6
```

And User table is

```
user
id name    user_type
1  raj     1
3  ram     1
4  anthony 2
6  kumar   2
```

Here in coloumn user_type 1 for user and 2 for field_tech

How can i do join and get the username and field tech name of the orders

I tried like

```
$data = Report::select('user.name as user_name')
                    ->leftjoin('users','users.id','=','report.user_id')
                    ->get();
```

But when i try

```
$data = Report::select('user.name as user_name')
                    ->leftjoin('users','users.id','=','report.user_id')
                    ->leftjoin('users','users.id','=','report.field_tech_id')
                    ->get();
```

How can i get the user name and field tech name ?

Comment: which table has  field tech name collumn

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
$data = Report::select('user.name as user_name')
                ->leftjoin('users as users1','users.id','=','report.user_id')
                ->leftjoin('users as users2','users.id','=','report.field_tech_id')
                ->select('users1.*,users2.*)                    
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass the whole SQL query then this should work:

```
SELECT u.name as user_name, r.field_tech_id
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN report r
ON u.id = r.user_id
```